# 2-categories for the working algebraic geometer

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

I study algebraic geometry / number theory and from time to time I stumble upon 2-categorical (co)limits. I have two main examples in mind:

> Example 1) In étale cohomology, the (triangulated) derived category of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_\ell}$-sheaves is defined as a 2-colimit of the derived categories of sheaves with coefficients in finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$.

> Example 2) The fact that $\textsf{QCoh}\to \textsf{Sch}$ is a stack should mean that, given a scheme $X$ and a covering $\{U_i\to X\}$, the category $\textsf{QCoh}(X)$ is a 2-limit of the $\textsf{QCoh}(U_i)$.

While the second example is somewhat straightforward, given that we may describe the limit as a category of descent data, the first one is awkward.

For sure, I shouldn't need to understand a lot of 2-category theory to make sense of these (and all related) examples. There are a lot of intricacies in the 2-categorical world... For example, should we consider (co)limits in the (2,0)-category of categories or on the (2,1)-category of categories? Should we consider lax 2-functors or strict 2-functors? What changes with those choices? (Bear in mind that I know very little of all of this.)

All in all, how should an algebraic geometer approach these kinds of statements? Also, is there a quick reference for all of this?

Comment: If you ever find yourself thinking about stacks, you will encounter a fair bit of 2-category theory. I think some introductions to stacks might cover some of the relevant background.

Comment: For everything you mentioned here (2,1)-categories are sufficient (where basically none of the subtleties of 2-category theory apply). In fact (∞,1)-category theory is much simpler than even 2-category theory...

Comment: I'm not sure you wrote what you meant to write for example 1. That example is pretty subtle though

Comment: @DonuArapura perhaps! Would you mind explaining a bit further?

Comment: @Gabriel Perhaps you meant to write "...the derived category of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_\ell$-sheaves...". As for the subtlety, see Ekedahl's paper *The adic formalism*.

Comment: Oh, that was absolutely a typo! Thanks for noticing!

Comment: To be honest I think the question is too broad and vague. Or is this just about the two examples? In any case, have a look at this book: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06055 It is a really good intro to 2-categories.

Comment: Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum's _A Study in Derived Algebraic Geometry_ [Volume I](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/GL/Vol1.pdf) and [Volume II](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/GL/Vol2.pdf) is a pioneering work which embraces $(\infty,2)$-categorical methods. But I'm sure Denis Nardin is right that the specific examples of statements you give might not be the places where this is most crucial.

Comment: Dear Martin and Tim, due to Denis Nardin's comment, my question is about (2,1)-categories. (The first reference seems to go deep into the intricacies of bicategories, and it's not really "quick". The second one is also not about (2,1)-categories.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard reference for category theory is *Categories for the Working Mathematician* (which I assume the OP knew about based on the question title). The closest reference I know to "2-categories for the working mathematician" is Steve Lack's *[A 2-categories companion](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702535v1)*, which presents the essential parts of the theory (including 2-limits, in Section 6) in only 73 pages. Lack is a famous 2-category theorist in Sydney, Australia, and throughout this monograph he emphasizes lax vs strict, pseudo vs strong, bicategories vs 2-categories, etc. He also discusses situations where the 2-cells are invertible. I mention this because of the comment telling the OP to look at (2,1)-categories.

Another nice (and much newer) reference is *[Elements of $\infty$-category theory](https://emilyriehl.github.io/files/elements.pdf)* by Emily Riehl and Dominic Verity. It's 606 pages, which might seem daunting, but Appendix B is an introduction to 2-category theory and is only 22 pages. An earlier draft of this book had the title *$\infty$-categories for the working mathematician*, and the book seems to be written with the goal of making the machinery easier to use, including to folks in algebraic geometry. Riehl and Verify are also world-class category theorists, and much of their approach to $\infty$-categories is 2-categorical in nature.